# How can I iterate over a TreeMap of type <Integer, ArrayList>

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, iterator, treemap

I have a TreeMap in which the keys are of type `Integer` and the values are of type `ArrayList`.

Here is some sample code:

```
import java.util.*;
public static void iterThruTreeMap() {
    ArrayList<String> contact = new ArrayList<String>();
    contact.add("Jane");
    contact.add("Doe");
    contact.add("123-456-7890");

    ArrayList<String> contact2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    contact2.add("Jane");
    contact2.add("Doe");
    contact2.add("123-456-7890");

    ArrayList<String> contact3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    contact3.add("Jane");
    contact3.add("Doe");
    contact3.add("123-456-7890");

    Map<Integer, ArrayList> list = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList>();
    list.put(0, contact);
    list.put(1, contact2);
    list.put(2, contact3);

    for (int key : list) {
        // stuck
    }
}
```

What I want to do is extract the first and last names from each of the `ArrayList`s contained in the `TreeMap`. I tried using a regular `for-loop` and received a `NullPointerException`. I am getting an error using the `foreach` method as shown in my sample, I think because of type.

I have tried using an `Iterator`, but I don't think I wrote it correctly. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it very much!

Comment: Hold up a second. Instead of `ArrayList`s, you should use an object `Person` which has the first name, last name, and phone number.

Comment: I think you need `for (List<String> list : map.values()) {` - note that I've changed the name of your `Map` from `list` (which it isn't) to `map` (which it is).

Comment: @DavidWallace would I use `for (List<String> list : map.values()) {` even though I now have `treeMap<Integer, SomeObject>`? I tried `for (Map.Entry<Integer, SomeObject> entry : treeMap.entrySet())` and I received an incompatibility error.

Comment: OK, I didn't realise you'd changed your `ArrayList` for a `SomeObject`.  Now, you'll be wanting `for (SomeObject person : treeMap.values()) {`.

Comment: Thanks. I had to fix a parameter and now all works. Much obliged!